# Execution of User Code from prompt in same document

Tags: javascript

I want to execute some code which I enter in a prompt dialog.

In the script tag , I have only this

```
code = prompt("");

code;
```

If I alert the code variable i have the proper string, however it wont execute that statement.

Is this even possible?

Comment: It is possible, but why? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty hard to make out what you're trying to achieve so I'm just guessing here. Is this what you're looking for?

```
var code = prompt("");
eval(code);
```

If not, apologies, but you really should word your questions better.

Answer (score 1):

`eval(code)` should do what you're asking to do.